# Get the Max and Min value and if values are same then print only one value, Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Fetch the Max and Min Value from the array and if the values are same then print only one value.
Error: I am getting all Price Value in foreach
Eg, Rs 120 120 120 120 120 120

```
<?php 
$maxprice = $product_attributes->max('price');
$minprice = $product_attributes->min('price'); ?>
  @foreach($product_attributes->sortBy('price') as $attribute)
    @if($maxprice === $minprice )
        {{ $attribute->price }}        
    @endif
  @endforeach
```

Comment: So what have you tried till now and what error are you facing?

Comment: I have updated Sehdev

Answer (score 2):

If you need to find `max` and `min` value from the collection.

```
$max = $product_attributes->max('price');
$min = $product_attributes->min('price');

@foreach($product_attributes->sortBy('price') as $attribute)
    @if($max === $min )
        {{ $attribute->price }}        
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Hi Amit, I have updated but still it's not getting any better result than simple for each

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupBy`

```
@foreach($product_attributes->groupBy('price')->sortBy('price')->values()->all() as $attribute)
{{ $attribute->price }} Rs 
@endforeach
```

Comment: Error 
Property [price] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: @Naren Explain more for what you need? And also `$product_attributes` array property.

Comment: @MdAbdulAwal, Thank you for the efforts, but it's still giving same error